# Advanced cakephp routes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I have a route like this:

```
Router::prefix('api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {        
    $routes->resources('Offers', function ($routes) {
        $routes->resources('SomeRelation', [
            'inflect' => 'dasherize',
            'path' => 'content',
        ]);
    });
});
```

I can access the page like this `/api/offers/148714/content`

This will redirect the URL to the `index()` action of my SomeRelation controller.
How can I change the action from index to any other action in the same controller?

I tried to change it according to the [cake manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#changing-the-controller-actions-used) but either it doesn't work with my case or I didn't get the structure right

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? It doesn't sound like a technical necessity, and most of the time people struggle with a problem that maybe should be solved differently. Also please always show what you've tried with regards to what the manualy says about modifying the action map, and describe what exactly happened - thanks!

Comment: @ndm I already use the index() function to list all the contents. This route should go to a filter funtion instead.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with the route I came up with the solution. Maybe it helps others.

```
Router::prefix('api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {        
    $routes->resources('Offers', function ($routes) {
        $routes->resources('SomeRelation', [
            'inflect' => 'dasherize',
            'path' => 'content',
            'actions' => ['index' => 'view'],
        ]);
    });
});
```